# Using NSubstitute is it possible to mock/stub a base class virtual method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have an inheritance hierachy that looks something like this;

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Don't want this to run");
    }
}

public class ConcreteImplementation1 : SomeBaseClass
{
}

public class ConcreteImplementation2 : ConcreteImplementation1
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This should run");
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Using NSubstitute I would like to stub ConcreteImplementation1's DoSomething() so that only the code in ConcreteImplementation2's DoSomething() method runs with the call to base.DoSomething() doing nothing.

Is this possible and if so how would I do this? Would the code look any different if DoSomething() were async?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with NSubstitute, or with .NET in general. NSubstitute [does support partial mocks](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/), but this is on a per-member basis.

So you can make it call `ConcreteImplementation2.DoSomething`, but that implementation calls `base.DoSomething` so that will execute:

```cs
var sub = Substitute.For<ConcreteImplementation2>();
sub.When(x => x.DoSomething()).CallBase();
```

NSubstitute [works by implementing/sub-classing a type](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/), so a good rule of thumb is that if you can't do something manually by sub-classing, NSubstitute will not be able to do it either.

In this case, if you create a `class ConcreteImplementation3 : ConcreteImplementation2` and override `DoSomething`, can you call `ConcreteImplementation2.DoSomething` without it calling `SomeBaseClass.DoSomething`? In this case I think the answer is no, so NSubstitute will not be able to do this either.